# Creating a view from JOIN two massive tables

Tags: sql, join, memory-leaks, impala

#### Context

I have a big table, say `table_A`, with roughly 20 billion rows and 600 columns. I don't own this table but I can read from it.

For a fraction of these columns I produce a few extra columns (50) which I store in a separate table, say `table_B`, which is therefore roughly 20 bn X 50 large.

Now I have the need to expose the join of table `table_A` and `table_B` to users, which I tried as

```sql
CREATE VIEW table_AB 
AS 
    SELECT *
    FROM table_A AS ta
    LEFT JOIN table_B AS tb ON (ta.tec_key = tb.tec_key)
```

The problem is that for any simple query like `SELECT * FROM table_AB LIMIT 2` will fail because of memory issues: apparently Impala attempts to do a full join first in memory which would result into a table of 0.5 Petabyte. Hence the failure.

#### Question

What is the best way to create such a view?

How can one instruct SQL that e.g. filtering operations are to be performed on `table_AB` are to be executed *before* the join?

Creating a new table is also suboptimal because it would mean duplicating the data in `table_AB`, using up hundreds of Terabytes.

I have also tried with `[...] SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN * [...]` but did not help.

Answer (score 1):

*What is the best way to create such a view?*
Since both tables are huge, there will be memory problem. here are some points i would recommend,

- Assuming table a and b have same tec_key, do a inner join
- Keep (smaller) table b as driver. `create vw as select ... from b join a on ...`. Impala stores driver table in memory and so it will require less memory.
- Select only columns required and do not select all.
- put filter in view.
- Do partitions in table b if you can on some dtae/year/region/anything that can evenly distribute the data.

*How can one instruct SQL that e.g. filtering operations are to be performed on table_AB are to be executed before the join?*

- You can not ensure filter goes before or after join. Only way to ensure a filter will improve perf is if you have partition on the filter column. Else, you can try to filter first and the join to see if it improves perf like this

```
select ... from b
join ( select ... from a where region='Asia') a on ... -- wont improve much
```

*Creating a new table is also suboptimal because it would mean duplicating the data in table_AB, using up hundreds of Terabytes.*

Completely agree on this. Multiple smaller tables is way better than one giant table with 600 columns. So, create few stg table with only required fields and then enrich that data. Its a difficult data set, but no one will change 20b rows everyday - so some sort of incremental is also possible to implement.